# Adding new value in an array to its proper index java

Tags: java, arrays

I have done a little exercise in my book about arrays. The point of the exercise is to add new value to an array if the new value is larger than the smallest. If the new value is larger than the smallest value in the array you have to remove it and add the new value in the array and place it to the right index without fully sorting the array.

```
sample input {54, 21, 2, 5, 8}
newValue = 17
```

In this case, the output will be `54, 21, 17, 5, 8`

I have done this perfectly, but there is one instance when I got it wrong and when I used the condition `(newVal > arr[j])` instead of `(newVal > arr[j-1])` in the loop where I assign the new value and I am expecting the error will be something like `arrayindexoutofboundsexception` but instead the output is `54, 17, 21, 5, 8` which is incorrect in this case because `17` is smaller than `21`. Can anyone tell me how did this happen?

Following is my code.

```
public static void addNewValue(int[] arr, int newVal) {
   //I did not include getMinValue() in this post. It just returns the index 
   //of the smallest value in the array
    int i = getMinValue(arr);
    for(; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
        arr[i] =  arr[i+1];
    }
    int j=arr.length-1;
    for(; (j>=1) && (newVal > arr[j-1]); j--) {
        arr[j] = arr[j-1];
    }
    arr[j] = newVal;        
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Put it at the right index without a full sort. But the source isn't sorted so where is it supposed to go; at the index of the smallest? If so, you already have that.

Comment: what I meant is placing it at the index starting the loop from the last array and just stop if it is lesser than the next. And my main question is about the condition inside the loop (newVal > arr[j-1]). Because on my first try I used (newVal > arr[j]) which is incorrect and the number 17 is placed on top of 21.

Comment: What if the newval is less than or equal to the smallest. you have modified the input array by copying all elements one index before. will that be a problem if input does not require modification.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear. Try to describe your problem in terms of *what you have to achieve* and *what you've tried*. I don't know about your first, second, or nth try, I only know what I see.

Comment: I don't get it, too. As I understand it, you just replace the smallest array item by `newVal` if `newVal` is larger. This can be done in about three lines of code: `int i = getMinValue(arr); if (arr[i] < newVal) arr[i] = newVal;`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main
{
 public static void main (String[]args)
 {


   int[] my_array = { 25, 14, 56, 15, 36, 56, 77, 18, 29, 49 };
   int[] my_array2 = new int[my_array.length+1];
  int removeIndex = 1;
  int j = 0;
  int k = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i <= my_array.length; i++)
   {
  if (i == 1)
    {
     my_array2[j] = 4;
     k = 1;
     j++;
    }

  else
   {

    my_array2[j] = my_array[i - k];
    j++;
       }
     }
    System.out.println ("Original Array : " + Arrays.toString (my_array2));
   }
  }
```